# How to initialize members of the base class subobject to 0?

Tags: c++, inheritance, object

```
class A
{
  public: int a,b,c;
};

class B: public A
{
   public: int d;
   B():d(0){} // Some hackery needed here
};

int main()
{
   B obj;
   std::cout<< obj.a << std::endl; // garbage
   std::cout<< obj.b << std::endl; // garbage
   std::cout<< obj.c << std::endl; // garbage
   std::cout<< obj.d << std::endl; // 0
}
```

How could the subobject data members a,b and c be initialized to 0? I am not permitted to modify class A.

Comment: "I am not permitted to modify class A." Why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
B() : A() , d(0){}
```

A() value initializes A and since A is a POD the members will be default(zero) initialized

---

Comment: Isn't the default constructor of A called by virtue of B inheriting from A?

Comment: Kristopher Johnson: `A()` would value initialize A.

Comment: @Prasoon: Some people are just here to downvote without knowing what they are doing, and without leaving even a comment!

Comment: I agree to Kristopher because the code above doesn't show A's constructor and we don't know if it initializes to 0, but I give +1 because it initializes the variables to their *default* values which is even better in most cases.

Comment: @schnaader: You're also wrong. Not only wrong, you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @Kristopher and @schnaader : Check out section 8.5/5 ISO C++03

Comment: OK, I'm now understanding it better. I guess the important passage is this one: "An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized"

Comment: and how come you get so many upvotes for beating me by a few seconds in posting the answer, other than you probably planted it as usual

Comment: @CashCow : Its just a matter of seconds. :)

Comment: ISTR that this is a change between C++03 and C++0X.  And g++ 4.4.4 doesn't set the members to 0.

Comment: your answer didn't work on gnu 4.3.2, by the way. I tested it.

Comment: @CashCow : It seems value initialization is not properly implemented in gnu 4.3.2. The solution works fine on g++ 4.5, clang++ and IntelC++ 11.0

Comment: How that people are testing.. Fails in gcc 3.4.6, 4.1.6 Works on MSVC 2010 EE, Sun C++ 5.8, gcc 4.5.2

Answer (score 4):

I tested this as I thought it might work (even without Prasoon's answer)

```
B::B() : A(), d(0)
{
}
```

might work, because you are then "initialising" A.

It didn't, by the way. Output:
1,32,123595988

This would work though:

```
// put this in B.cpp anonymous namespace
const A a_init = { 0, 0 ,0 };
```

followed by:

```
B::B() : A( a_init), d(0)
{
}
```

I am testing using g++ 4.3.2. Now **THIS** worked:

```
B::B() : A(A()), d(0)
{
}
```

Comment: Try it on compilers which have properly implemented value initialization :)

Comment: @Prasoon: Anyway, this is a good answer as it shows there are compilers where this doesn't work. Would be good to know which compiler was used, though.

Comment: @Prasoon My initial reaction was the same solution as yours, although in the practical world, unless you are writing only for your only compiler you write code that works on some old ones too. You could put in a preprocessor, i.e. #if _GNUC_VERSION > 4.5 or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but how about this?

```
class B: public A
{
    public: int d;
    B():d(0){a=b=c=0;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare the derived class constructor as  shown below

```
class B: public A
{
   public: int d;
   B():a(0),b(0),c(0),d(0)
   {

   }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is of course to have A's constructor initialize it's members. Otherwise, as the members are not private, you can assign them values from inside the B constructor.

```
a = 0;
```

etc, actually works.